# How to make it preserve HTML tags if each line of text is wrapped with a div tag?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm seeking assistance regarding a code I have. It wraps each line of text with a div tag. However, the issue is that it doesn't account for HTML tags such as `<a> or <span>`. I'm struggling to figure out how to modify it to preserve these HTML tags within the text. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I haven't been able to solve this on my own.

```js
// Wrapping lines
function splitLines(container, opentag, closingtag) {
  let $lines = container.children,
    $top = 0,
    $tmp = "";
  container.innerHTML = container.textContent.replace(/\S+/g, "<n>$&</n>");
  for (let i = 0; i < $lines.length; i++) {
    let $rect = $lines[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
    if ($top < $rect) $tmp += closingtag + opentag;
    $top = $rect;
    $tmp += $lines[i].textContent + " ";
  }
  container.innerHTML = $tmp += closingtag;
}

splitLines( $(".wrap-lines")[0], '<div class="line-wrap"><div class="line">', "</div></div>" );


/* Button */
let $button = gsap.from(".line", { duration: 0.5, yPercent: 100, stagger: 0.2, clearProps:"all" });
$(".btn-lines").on("click", function() {
  $button.restart();
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 5% 10%;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}
p {
  font-size: 21px;
}

p span {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.line-wrap {
  display: inline-flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gsap@3/dist/gsap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  
  <!-- With wrapping lines -->
  <h1>With wrapping lines (HTML tags don't work)</h1>
  <p class="wrap-lines">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet <a href="">consectetur</a> adipisicing elit. Animi dolorem quasi aut dolore porro <span>iusto in facilis</span>, molestias nostrum possimus ipsum laboriosam dolorum voluptatibus praesentium consequuntur! Culpa quas nisi hic.</p>
  
  <button class="btn-lines">Animate Lines</button>
  
  <br>
  <br>

  <!-- Without wrapping lines -->
  <h1>Without wrapping lines (HTML tags work)</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet <a href="">consectetur</a> adipisicing elit. Animi dolorem quasi aut dolore porro <span>iusto in facilis</span>, molestias nostrum possimus ipsum laboriosam dolorum voluptatibus praesentium consequuntur! Culpa quas nisi hic.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Use `.innerHTML` rather than `.textContent`. `textContent` removes tags.

Comment: Do you realize that jQuery has a `.wrap()` method?

Comment: I don't see any span tags in the code.

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. You assign `container.innerHTML` before the loop, then you assign it again after the loop. So the first assignment is ignored.

Comment: .innerHTML doesn't give the desired result, it displays the tags as plain text.

Comment: No it doesn't. That would happen if you assign the innerHTML to innerText. If you read and write innerHTML, it parses the tags.

Comment: I see the problem. You're just getting the contents of each child, and putting that content into the container. You need to get the whole tag, not just its contents. Use `outerHTML` to get that.

Comment: If I may ask, what's the purpose of your task at all? Seems like an [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What is that you're actually trying to create?

Comment: What if any child element spans two or more *"rows"*? Why do you create (define) functions inside an each loop? (That's an antipattern). Why do you need that lines highlighting at all? Have you thought about just getting the line height, then getting the cursor's Y position any simply color the background of that parent using linear gradient? Or at least moving an absolute element?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't explain it more simply. I want each line of text to be wrapped in a div tag (as my code currently does) and at the same time the HTML tags (<a>, <span>, etc..) to be preserved in the text (this is what I can't figure out on my own). The highlighted lines on hover are just for demo purposes.

Comment: Here is CodePen for better understanding: https://codepen.io/Juku321/pen/BaMbPvW

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing stems from the fact that when you replace the text content with HTML tags, it loses the existing HTML structure.

Updated (5.58pm IST)

```
function wrapLines(container, opentag, closingtag) {
  const lines = container.innerHTML.split('\n');

  const wrappedLines = lines.map(line => {
    if (line.trim() !== "") {
      return opentag + line + closingtag;
    }
    return line; 
  });

  container.innerHTML = wrappedLines.join('');
}

wrapLines($(".wrap-lines")[0], '<div class="line-wrap"><div class="line">', "</div></div>");

/* Button */
let $button = gsap.from(".line", { duration: 0.5, yPercent: 100, stagger: 0.2, clearProps:"all" });
$(".btn-lines").on("click", function() {
  $button.restart();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but your code wrapping every word, not every line of text.

Comment: Hi @mrWilson! How about split the content based on line breaks (\n). I have modified the code and updated my answer. Please let know the status. Thank You!

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I need the entire line of text to be wrapped. Your solution does not wrap HTML tags.

Comment: Hi! I again updated my answer. Please see whether updated solution is working for you.

Comment: Now it wraps the entire text, not each line individually. :(

Comment: I've updated my answer one again. If it does not work properly, it is beyond my limits. However please let me know the status. Extremely sorry.

Comment: Unfortunately, no luck. :( It still wraps the entire text, not each line individually. Thanks for trying to help. I appreciate it very much.

Comment: Hope someone will assist you. Try by modify the code. You might find a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Use `$lines[i].outerHTML` instead of `$lines[i].textContent` so you get the entire HTML of the tag, not just its text.

```js
$(".wrap-lines").each(function () {
  let $lineWrapper = this;
  
  function splitLines(container, opentag, closingtag) {
    let $lines = container.children,
      $top = 0,
      $tmp = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < $lines.length; i++) {
      let $rect = $lines[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
      if ($top < $rect) $tmp += closingtag + opentag;
      $top = $rect;
      $tmp += $lines[i].outerHTML + " ";
    }
    container.innerHTML = $tmp += closingtag;
  }

  //splitLines( $(this)[0], '<div class="line">', "</div>" );

});
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 24px;
}
p span {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.line:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Wrapping text lines</h1>

<p class="wrap-lines">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet <a href="">consectetur</a> adipisicing elit. Animi dolorem quasi aut dolore <span>porro iusto</span> in facilis, molestias nostrum possimus ipsum laboriosam dolorum voluptatibus praesentium consequuntur! Culpa quas nisi hic.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I want each line of text to be wrapped in a div tag, and at the same time the HTML tags (<a>, <span>, etc..) to be preserved in the text.

Comment: Here is CodePen for better understanding: https://codepen.io/Juku321/pen/BaMbPvW

Comment: Put it in the Stack Snippet in the question, not a remote codepen.

Comment: Please edit the question and show what the desired HTML looks like.

Comment: I've edited my original question, hopefully, it's better understood now what I'm trying to achieve.